# octomap_server nodelet missing under Hydro

Tags: octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

1. After successfully running octomap_server as node, I would like to try running it as nodelet. If I `roslaunch octomap_server octomap_mapping_nodelet.launch` I get the following error:

   [ERROR] [1384422211.742630096]: Failed to load nodelet [/octomap_server_nodelet] of type [octomap_server/OctomapServerNodelet]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class octomap_server/OctomapServerNodelet with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist.

Looking at the contents of `/opt/ros/hydro/share/octomap_server`, I can see that there is no `nodelet_plugins.xml` file in there. I am using the latest octomap_server binary package that comes with Hydro. The dev version, however, does contain the nodelet definition file, see https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/tree/hydro-devel/octomap_server/plugins

2. When cloning https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping.git into my workspace and compiling it with catkin_make, I get this "no matching function" error:

   In file included from /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/octomap_mapping/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerMultilayer.cpp:30: /opt/ros/hydro/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h: In function ‘void pcl_conversions::fromPCL(const PointIndices&, pcl_msgs::PointIndices&)’: /opt/ros/hydro/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:265:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘fromPCL(const *header_type&, pcl_msgs::PointIndices*std::allocator<void >::_header_type&)’

@AHornung:Any idea what is broken here?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101091/octomap_server-nodelet-missing-under-hydro/) by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 399 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding 1: Looks like the file `nodelet_plugins.xml` is not installed via CMake so it's missing from the binary install. This could be related to [this issue on octomap_mapping](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/issues/1). That should be easy to fix similar to this commit/patch: https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/commit/784e5c6d590e605315fb90c2fc350cc20b4e0cae

Regarding 2: Cloning the devel version (hydro-devel branch) should definitely work and compile, I just verified. Could it be that you have an outdated version of `pcl_conversions` installed?

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Huibuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4959/huibuh/) on 2013-11-14**:
Thanks Armin, I managed to resolve both issues. 1): Now using octomap_mapping compiled from source which included the nodelet definition. 2): My catkin_ws was currupted. After deleting the build and devel folders and recreating them the octomap_mapping package compiled without errors. Thanks, Heiko

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-11-14**:
I just pushed the fix for the installation to the hydro-devel branch, will be part of the next release.